# Where are stdin, stdout files located in Windows?

Tags: c, windows, file, stdout, stdin

Whenever I execute a C program, there are 3 standard files, `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`. Theses map to `/proc/self/fd/0`, `/proc/self/fd/1`, `/proc/self/fd/2` in Linux, which link to `/dev/pts/0` in my computer. This is pseudo-terminal, to which this process outputs to and takes inputs from.

What is the equivalent of this in Windows? Where do these `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` point to, when I execute same program in Windows?

Comment: I don't think Windows provides access to those via a pseudo file-system like Linux does, but I'm not sure.  Why do you need them? What do you want to do?

Comment: @TedLyngmo to answer why I wanted them, I was thinking if C standards did not provide `stdX`, how to take input and display output. In Linux this can be done by opening `/dev/pts/0` or `/dev/tty` file. In Windows, what is the solution?

Comment: _"how to take input and display output"_ - but, you have `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` for that already?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I said 'if C standards did not provide `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` then'...

Comment: `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`, and the integer fd's 0, 1, and 2 they're based on, existed *long* before `/proc/self/fd` did.  The latter is a convenience (and a huge one!), but it's hardly fundamental to the implementation of the standard-file-descriptor concept.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On a Linux kernel, the `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` streams have corresponding entries in `/proc`.  That `/proc` filesystem is an informational structure which provides visibility into the system; it is not the implementation of these streams.

Firstly, `stdout` is a C concept: an instance of a `FILE *` I/O stream. The operating system kernel (whether it be Linux or Windows) doesn't know anything about this. These streams hold operating system file descriptors/handles. A Linux or Windows program has a `stdout` stream due to being linked to a C library, which may not be true of a program that is not written in C, or a C-based language that uses a C run-time.

A process in an a Unix-like operating system has numbered file descriptors, starting at zero. The first three—0, 1 and 2—are, by convention, input, output and error.

In Microsoft Windows, there is a similar concept. A process has three handles of type `HANDLE` which serve the same purpose. When you create a process using `CreateProcess`, they are specified in the `STARTUPINFO` structure which has these members:

```
HANDLE hStdInput;
HANDLE hStdOutput;
HANDLE hStdError;
```

which are meaningful if the `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` flag is specified.

Microsoft Windows doesn't have a `/proc` filesystem. It has API-based mechanisms for inspecting various system states. System utilities are written to these API's. For instance, the [Handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) program can be used for inspecting what processes have what files open.
A similar application on Linux would traverse `/proc` under the hood.

Comment: If suppose C standards did not provide `stdin`, `stdout`, how to take input and display output. In Linux this can be done by opening `/dev/pts/0` or `/dev/tty` file. In Windows, what is the solution?

Comment: If you don't use a C library, or work in C at all, you don't have to open any `/dev/` device. You have file descriptor 0, 1 and 2, which were set up by and inherited from the parent process.   Windows programs similarly receive the three handles from `CreateProcess`, or at least optionally.

Comment: In Windows, you can use the function `GetStdHandle` to obtain any one of the three handles that were passed to the process. Thus no C library is needed, just these funtions in `kernel32.lib`.

Answer (score 2):

They don't exist as files on Windows. Even though Windows NT has a object manager in the kernel where named kernel objects exist, the console is not part of it.

At the Win32 layer, those 3 handles are returned by [`GetStdHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle). They are special handles and when `WriteFile`/`ReadFile` are called, they check for these special handles and reroutes the request to the console API internally. On the other hand, if a std handle is redirected then the handle can be a real file on disk or a pipe and normal I/O is performed. `CON`, `CONIN$` and `CONOUT$` are special names known by `CreateFile` and provides access to the console screen buffers but this is not exactly the same thing as the handles from `GetStdHandle`.

The C run-time library sits on top of Win32 and provides another level of abstraction. Internally it will have mappings to/from std, FILE* and the native Win32 HANDLE.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct equivalent of /dev/stdin and other Unix pseudo files.

You could create a named pipe (CreateNamedPipe) but it isn't exactly identical.

The windows files conIN$ and conOUT$ are similar, but they only read or write to the current window.